# Will new Date().toJSON() always be unique in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, pouchdb

The [PouchDB Manual](https://pouchdb.com/guides/bulk-operations.html) suggests using `Date().toJSON()` to generate a new id for each document.  Do all javascript runtimes guarantee that `Date().toJSON()` will always be unique?

Comment: no, it won't be unique - if you and I run that at exactly the same moment, we'll get exactly the same result. And, `console.log(new Date().toJSON(),new Date().toJSON())` will produce the identical output twice most of the time as well - so, no

Comment: `new Date().toJSON() + Math.random() + Math.random()` is more likely to be unique

Comment: why aren't you using a salted hash value of fixed length  for random id generation + incrementor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dates only have microsecond precision, so there's no guarantee they will be unique.

The snippet below will give you a number of duplicates in all but the slowest runtime environments:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(new Date().toJSON())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of distributed system, We can also use this [eventid](https://github.com/google/eventid-js) module.

Answer (score 0):

I think the PouchDb guide mentioned using dates in that example so that documents would be in date/time order, not that this would ensure uniqueness. In [the API](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_create) you can see that if you do not specify an ID PouchDb will create a unique one for you.

Comment: I've always assumed that _id had semantics similar to that of a sql primary key, but perhaps that's not the case?  I'll start a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430626/must-pouchdb-id-property-values-have-to-be-globally-unique